# how do i find documents whose latest check date is after 2020?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i'm new to mongodb. my documents like this, some of the document’s log is empty, and some of the log’s check_date contains empty:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60176a4e771e0000e2007db8"), "file" : 1, "log" : [ { "check_date" : ISODate("1991-01-01T00:00:00Z") }, { "check_date" : ISODate("1992-01-01T00:00:00Z") }, {  } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60176a4e771e0000e2007db9"), "file" : 2, "log" : [ { "check_date" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z") }, { "check_date" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z") }, { "check_date" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00Z") }, {  } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60176a4e771e0000e2007dba"), "file" : 3, "log" : {  } }
```

how do i find documents whose latest check date is after 2020(file 2)?

this is my query, but returns 0 files:

```
[
  {$match:{log.check_date:{$exists:1}}},
  {$redact:{
    $cond:{
      if:{$gt:[{$max:[$log.check_date]}, "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"]},
      then:$$KEEP,  
      else:$$PRUNE
      }
   }}
]
```

The reason why empty log is {} instead of [] is because these documents are R's nested data frame. the log of file 3 is not a cell of a data frame with 0 rows, but a cell with NULL.

```
> x
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   file log             
  <int> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [3 x 1]>
2     2 <tibble [4 x 1]>
3     3 <NULL>
```

Comment: How come the empty `log` field is an empty object `{}`? Shouldn't it be an empty array `[]`?

Comment: I think this is the result of inserting nested data frame from R.I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your documents contain timestamps ("BSON date" instances) but you are querying with strings. You need to query with timestamps also.